# Is thermodynamics a physical theory?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, terminology, models, laws-of-physics

It looks like to me that whenever we need to describe something we start from observations which lead to a theory. All theories seem to rely on laws:

- theory of classical mechanics

  - Newton's laws
- theory of relativity

  - special relativity

    - Einstein's postulates
- theory of quantum

  - Uncertainty principle
  - Some others which I am not aware of

From these fundamental laws you can derive all the equations that describe a phenomenon within that framework (or theory if you want).

If my assumptions are correct, is thermodynamics a theory since it relies on its own laws? Or does it fall within some of the before mentioned theories and therefore the laws are a consequence of something else?

Note: feel free to correct my initial statement if you want as well.

Comment: I do not want to repeat my answer here but it is relevant to your question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150285/proof-in-physics/150292#150292

Comment: Are you saying that a particular subject should only be considered a theory if its foundations are disconnected from every other area of physics? Why do you think being so restrictive with your language is helpful? Physics is a science - different fields mingle with and borrow from one another constantly, in a way which would make it impossible to disentangle them as strictly as you seem to want to.

Comment: @J.Murray nope, that is not what I am saying nor implying. I am just trying to understand if a difference exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between thermodynamics and mechanics (whether Newtonian or quantum or general relativity) is subtle. It is like the relationship between momentum conservation and Newton's Laws of motion. Or, a better comparison, it is like the relationship between translational invariance and Newton's Laws.

To explain what I mean without writing a long essay, consider what you think about the way momentum conservation relates to Newton's Second and Third Laws. Is it the case that the Second and Third Laws are the fundamental axiom, and momentum conservation follows? Or is it that momentum conservation is the more basic idea, and the Third Law can be derived? Most people would find it hard to say. But we can also derive momentum conservation from another idea, namely translational invariance i.e. the postulate that the laws of motion should only depend on relative not absolute locations. So now we have this general idea of invariance underpinning Newtonian mechanics, and it also underpins quantum mechanics.

But someone might still insist that, no, it is the Laws of Motion which 'rule', and translational invariance follows as a consequence, not an axiom.

But such an assertion fails to notice that translational invariance was built in to the very concepts one was using!

The general result is that pinning down exactly what is and is not being assumed in any given area of physics is itself a non-trivial task.

Coming now to thermodynamics, we have big ideas such as thermal equilibrium, energy conservation, and the increase of entropy. Are these merely consequences of whatever mechanics describes the universe? The question is, what is the word "merely" doing there? One could equally well argue that energy conservation is such a basic idea that quantum theory has to respect it (when spacetime is not itself dynamic). So which one 'rules'? There is no way to give an objective answer to that question. The two approaches are mutually consistent.

Many textbooks will assert that thermodynamics is simply a convenient approximation to some fundamental mechanical theory when many bodies are involved. But I think such statements fail to appreciate that the principles from which thermodynamics is built up (the notions of equilibrium, energy and entropy) are already well-defined physical ideas before anyone ever brings in any particular description of mechanics etc. Such concepts have an equal claim to the adjective "fundamental" as do any other concepts in physics. To make the same point in a more mathematical way: you could simply omit from some physical theory certain features so as to make that theory incomplete and not able to furnish full descriptions of physical behaviour. And then, to complete the theory, one could simply add the laws of thermodynamics. This isn't how we normally proceed but it makes the point that thermodynamics can be seen as just as basic a part of our insight into the natural world as any other set of ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not written very well. Anyway...

**Thermodynamics is a physical theory**

I can't agree with you if you really mean the thermodynamics is not a physical theory. Let's focus here on classical thermodynamics, the one studied in high school and in the first years at the university, and see why it can be considered a physical theory:

- It starts from experiments, historically on gases and fluids in general (in the '700-early '800 they were interested in using gases in mechanical power generation, e.g. in steam engines)
- it postulates some principles as the fundamental laws of the theory, the $0^{th}$ principle stating the thermal equilibrium and the other 3 principles of thermodynamics, stating

  1. the balance of the total energy of a close system, $d E^{tot} = \delta L^{ext} + \delta Q^{ext}$, being $\delta L$ the elementary work done on the system, and $\delta Q$ the elementary heat flux making the total energy of the system increase ("entering the system")
  2. a "natural" direction of the physical processes, through the concept of entropy
  3. a lower limit value and an absolute meaning of the temperature
- from the principles, along with constitutive laws describing the behaviour of the media investigated derived from experimental measurements (as an example, the law of ideal gas $P = \rho R T$), it finds some laws that govern equilibrium states of "complex" systems. From the very principles of thermodynamics, it's possible to derive the equations governing a very wide spectrum of different physical phenomena, from simple transformation of gases and the conversion of work and heat in energy in power generation with heat engines, to phase transition, to heat transfer in different kind of media, to a more detailed description of mechanical systems in presence of friction that dissipates mechanical work into heat. Moreover, through the local equilibrium principle, thermodynamics is a fundamental theory upon continuum mechanics relies.

**Thermodynamics is usually presented in a very bad manner at schools and in books (personal considerations)**

I don't know why, but it seems to me that thermodynamics is presented in a very messy way, in average. It's usually presented with the experiments on ideal gases, without clearly stating that they are a very particular system that can be described by principles of thermodynamics; moreover, when you deal with the experiments on ideal gases at school, it's likely that you can't understand that you're not studying principles of thermodynamics but you're studying the constitutive law of that system, i.e. a mathematical expression that tells you how the system behave.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt answer. So for me what is was misleading is the naming actually. For example fluid dynamics is not a physical theory since it's equations are derived from the application of classical mechanics and thermodynamics. However both fluid dynamics and thermodynamics end with the same word so I was a bit confusing.

Comment: Even Fluid Dynamics can be considered a "theory", or better a *branch* of Physics. It just relies on the same principles of classical mechanics and thermodynamics, along with the **continuum assumption** and the **local equilibrium assumption**. I tell you to use *branch* because it's not just theory, but also experimental (and nowadays numerical) activities

Comment: Yeah but I want to be quite strict in the naming convention because if fluid dynamics relies on principle of 2 theories it cannot be defined as a theory. I would rather use the word branch as you suggested. 

Using this convention what would you say about electromagnetism? is it more a branch of physics or a stand-alone theory? I see that the Maxwell's equations come from laws such as Biot-Savart or Gauss which seem to be defined by observation rather than applying Newton's law or Thermodynamic laws. What is your opinion?

Comment: Broadly speaking, Physics could be interpreted as the the study of Nature, using a scientific approach. I think that nobody has ever drawn a sharp boundary to the field of Physics, by I'd be very confident that electromagnetic phenomena belongs to the fundamentals of Nature, so EM is a *branch* of Physics. Principles of Classical Electromagnetism are usually considered to be Maxwell equations (i.e. Gauss'laws for electric and magnetic fields, Biot-Savart law, Ampere law), and Lorenz force. These historically come from experimental activities of the '800, and are usually accepted as principles

Comment: @Chemomechanics thanks for you review

Answer (score 2):

Thermodynamics is manifestly a physical theory in that it is a theoretical framework that is used to explain observed features of the physical world.

However, I think what you are getting at is that thermodynamics is perhaps not *fundamental* as a starting point for describing physical laws.

From a hard-nosed, reductionist point of view, I think this point of view has some merit. From our current state of knowledge, we can say that the Standard Model plus General Relativity viewed as an effective field theory of gravity give a complete description of all known observable physical phenomena. We could speculate that in the future, there may be some theory of everything that unifies gravity with the Standard Model which may then be an even more fundamental starting point. From this point of view, statistical mechanics is a tool that naturally arises we use to describe many degrees of freedom obeying these microscopic laws -- not a fundamental requirement, but a tool used to cope with large systems. Thermodynamics, in turn, can be understood as a useful *effective* description of many degrees of freedom, derivable from statistical mechanics.

Having said that, there is an aspect to thermodynamics that is apparently "universal" and which does not really depend on the exact microscopic laws that underpin it. For example, while it was derived in the context of classical physics, its principles apply perfectly well to quantum systems as well (in fact arguably some aspects of thermodynamics make *more* sense in quantum mechanics, such as the Gibbs paradox). Arthur Eddington famously said

> The law that entropy always increases holds, I think, the supreme position among the laws of Nature. If someone points out to you that your pet theory of the universe is in disagreement with Maxwell's equations - then so much the worse for Maxwell's equations. If it is found to be contradicted by observation - well, these experimentalists do bungle things sometimes. But if your theory is found to be against the Second Law of Thermodynamics I can give you no hope; there is nothing for it to collapse in deepest humiliation.

There is certainly an uncomfortable philosophical tension, between the tendency of many physicists to be *reductionist* and seek fundamental laws, and the existence of emergent phenomena that do not depend strongly on those fundamental laws. You may be interested in reading about the debate surrounding [emergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence) in physics. I think it is an issue worth grappling with and thinking about.

My personal take on this (which is just one person's opinion!) is that there are some fundamental principles (like locality and Lorentz invariance) baked into our microscopic laws that are more important than the precise form of the laws themselves. These principles in turn imply that thermodynamics will hold in an appropriate limit. In that sense, the applicability of thermodynamics is tied deeply to those principles, and so I would say is a fundamental part of the framework of physics as a whole.