# In which systems does Planck's constant apply? Is everything thus quantized?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

As a child my father told me about Planck's constant and I wonder whether I may have been confused. I imagined that *all* metrics are thus quantized, e.g. space has a minimum unit of distance, so for electrical charge, speed, etc.

Reading the Wiki, the extent to which this intuition is correct us unclear: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant

Can anyone shed light on this/recommend some good reading material? Thank you!

Comment: Hello Oliver. We don't know whether space is discrete or not, if that's the question.

Comment: maybe my answer here will summarize what physics is about , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150285/proof-in-physics/150292#150292

Comment: You *really* mean the [Planck Length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Planck_length), no? Not the Planck constant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, at the classical or macroscopic level, not all things are quantized, e.g. the energy of a ball rolling downhill or the amount of soup a person can eat in the morning. However, at the fundamental level there are indeed many examples of quantization in nature: charge comes in integer multiples of $e$, and the electromagnetic, weak and strong interactions have been quantized. However, the gravitational interaction, one of the four fundamental interactions found in nature, has not yet been successfully put on a quantized basis, i.e. there is no complete quantum theory of gravity. The modern Einsteinian theory of gravity is a field theoretic development of the geometry of space-time in correlation with matter-energy density that no one yet understands at the plank level of distance, or at correspondingly high energies.

Good reading? there is much literature on the subject, and it would be easier to recommend something if the community knew your level of competence with mathematics and physics. Assuming you are a beginner, try reading George Gamow's *Thirty Years that Shook Physics* and Albert Einstein's *Relativity* for aged but good introductions to quantum and relativistic physics. For a more modern read that talks more about the quantum gravity and related problems specifically, see Michio Kaku's *Beyond Einstein*.

Answer (score 0):

Most physical interactions we know of are currently described by quantum mechanical theories. At present, there are multiple candidates for a quantum theory of space and time, which would also be a quantum theory of gravity.

Some physicists claim that gravity may not be quantum mechanical and we can only determine that issue by experiment:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.12221

Others claim that under plausible assumptions gravity has to be quantised to have a theory of gravity that is consistent with quantum theory:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04325